# How to plot 2 histograms on 1 graph from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to plot one histogram that shows the frequency counts of hotwings consumed by gender. It is two histograms in 1 plot.

```
id Hotwings    Beer Gender
1   4   24  F
2   5   0   F
3   5   12  F
4   6   12  F
5   7   12  F
6   7   12  F
7   7   24  M
8   8   24  F
9   8   0   M
10  8   12  M
11  9   24  F
12  11  24  F
13  11  24  M
14  12  30  F
15  12  30  F
16  13  24  F
17  13  36  F
18  13  30  M
19  13  30  M
20  14  30  F
21  14  36  F
22  14  48  M
23  16  36  M
24  16  36  M
25  17  36  M
26  17  42  M
27  18  30  M
28  18  30  M
29  21  36  M
30  21  42  M
```

This is my dataset above...

plt.hist([data["Hotwings"][data["Gender"]=='M']],[data["Hotwings"][data["Gender"]=='F']])

I keep receiving the `bins` must be 1d, when an array, error. I am extremely confused on how to proceed or if there is a better way to do this using matplotlib. Thanks!

EDIT:
I also tried this:

plt.hist(dta[dta["Gender"]=='M'][data["Hotwings"]],[data["Gender"]=='F'][data["Hotwings"]])

and I got a keyError: "None of [Int64Index([ 4,  5,  5,  6,  7,  7,  7,  8,  8,  8,  9, 11, 11, 12, 12, 13, 13,\n            13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 16, 16, 17, 17, 18, 18, 21, 21],\n           dtype='int64')] are in the [columns]"

I am really confused and unsure how to make the bars side by side

Answer (score 1):

This will show your bar in same graph

```
plt.bar(dta[dta['Gender']=='F']['Hotwings']-1, dta[dta['Gender']=='F']['Beer'], 0.50, align='center', alpha=0.5, color='b')

plt.bar(dta[dta['Gender']=='M']['Hotwings']+1, dta[dta['Gender']=='M']['Beer'], 0.50, align='center', alpha=0.5, color='r')
plt.show()
```

And to show graph in different Graph you can use.

```
sp = plt.subplot(2,2,1)
l1 = plt.bar(dta[dta['Gender']=='F']['Beer'], dta[dta['Gender']=='F']['Hotwings'], 3.0, align='center', alpha=0.5, color='b')

sp = plt.subplot(2,2,2)
l1 = plt.bar(dta[dta['Gender']=='M']['Beer'], dta[dta['Gender']=='M']['Hotwings'], 2.0, align='center', alpha=0.5, color='r')
plt.show()
```

Comment: second one show graph side by side.
and you can change graph size. by
plt.figure(figsize=(18, 16), dpi= 80, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')

Comment: I mean like the bars side by side. Not the graphs itself.

Comment: add a number with you column value. I have updated the first code.

Answer (score 0):

```
data.groupby("Gender")["Hotwings"].plot(kind="hist")
plt.legend() # optional, but recommended
plt.show()
```